# How to Change Redux Persisted Data after Logged In as Different User

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

So I'm developing a React-Native App and in my app's store I persist `ratedPosts` to keep the info of user's rated posts.

*(Other way to get this info is iterating rated users list of each post, since that way would consume more performance I came up with this solution)*

### **redux store**

[image: redux-store]

However, I just noticed after I logged as different user to my app, persisted data still loads which normally what I should've expected. Is there a way for change persisted data for different users? Like after I log in as `user1` this data loads and for `user2` ratedPosts is empty.

### **store.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

import rootReducer from './src/reducers'

const initialState = {}

const middleware = [thunk]

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage: AsyncStorage,
    whitelist: [
        'ratedPosts',
        'addedPosts'
    ],
    timeout: 0
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

const store = createStore(
    persistedReducer,
    initialState,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
)

const persistor = persistStore(store)

export { store, persistor }
```

Answer (score 0):

On user changed event, your app should :

1. ACTION: dispatch USER_CHANGED action
2. REDUCER: ratedPosts:{}, addedPosts: {}

Persisted data will sync and change accordingly

Comment: But won't this way reset `ratedPosts` and `addedPosts` every time user changed? So first added data  won't come back after logged back as `user1`.

Comment: But won't this way reset ratedPosts and addedPosts every time user changed?  yes

What data would you like to keep in case users change ?